# Flutter app closes when outside of an app

Tags: flutter, dart

My problem is that, my app closes instantly when I check smth for a moment outside of an app.

It is quite a problem, because I want to use multifactor authentication. When I go for a moment to authenticating app to get verification code, my app already closes and its state is lost.

Is there a way I can help it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: can you share your stacktrace?

Comment: which state management are you using?

Comment: chech this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47635

Comment: @Vettiyanakan thank you

Comment: did you manage to fix it?